# Selenium unable to start Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, pycharm

I'm trying to make a simple scraping program but I am not able to get Selenium working with Firefox. I installed [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) but that didn't solve anything. When I type this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'

Also, PyCharm gives this warning:

> 'Firefox' is not callable

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you specify Firefox and selenium versions please?

Comment: I already got the solution, but for anyone running into the same problem: I'm currently on Firefox 49.0.1 and Selenium 3.0.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path to your driver")
```

eg: `driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\Python27\wires.exe")`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the complete path to firefox executable. Maybe it's not listed in you variable environment path..

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox("/path/to/firefox")
```

This should tell your script where to find the firefox executable.

**Edit:**

If you're using Windows, try using double slashes.

I.e.: `'C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe'`

Or marking it as a raw string:

I.e.: `r'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'`

Comment: Now I get this error: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'. However, that is the directory of my firefox executable and I'm able to launch it from there.

Comment: **After edit:** I got the same error: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe'

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following lines of Code to run Firefox with Selenium 3:

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
ff_Binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary = ff_Binary)
```